# Colorbox iFrame not loading certain urls

Tags: url, iframe, colorbox

Does anyone know why Colorbox is not loading certain pages? I am wanting to load Google Maps on an address I have but it doesn't seem to work. I looked at the examples, and it loads Wikipedia, other known websites, and Bing.com including its maps. It does not load Google, Facebook, Twitter, or Pinterest. Although it does load Tumblr (but opens it up on the parent page and not in the iframe.

So I'm guessing Colorbox doesn't allow social media websites in the iframe? Has anyone had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Iframe does not load Google, Facebook, Twitter, or Pinterest, is because those sites have "X-Frame-Options: Deny" set on server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288472(v=vs.85).aspx#search

Clickjacking Defense: Some hackers try to trick users into clicking buttons that appear to perform safe or harmless functions, but instead perform unrelated tasks. Clickjackers embed malicious code or "redress" the user interface by using transparent frames that overlay specific UI elements with misleading text and images. To help prevent clickjacking, Web site owners can send an HTTP response header named X-Frame-Options with HTML pages to restrict how the page may be framed.

X-Frame-Options: Deny

If the X-Frame-Options value contains the token Deny, Internet Explorer 8 prevents the page from rendering if it is contained within a frame. If the value contains the token SameOrigin, Internet Explorer will not render the page if the top level-browsing-context differs from the origin of the page containing the directive. Blocked pages are replaced with a "This content cannot be displayed in a frame" error page.